# Why does bidirectional @OneToMany work without second save()

Tags: hibernate

According to [this fabulous article by Thorben Janssen](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/) a bidirectional association for @OneToMany works like this:

```
Item item3 = new Item();
item3.setName("Third Item");
item3.setOrder(order);
em.persist(item3);
 
order = em.find(PurchaseOrder.class, orderId);
order.getItems().add(item3);
```

In other words,

1. Persist the owner of the @ManyToOne relationship
2. Just add the owner to the @OneToMany entity, you don't even need to call save() a second time

Now, why is that? I implemented this and played around with some tests just to get this right. For me personally, this is highly obfuscated hibernate magic and this behavior does not make sense.

This is why I want to dive deeper into how Hibernate works so I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening here. I know the entities are tied to the hibernate persistence layer but from here on my knowledge gets a bit wonky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what's going on you need to be familiar with [Hibernate ORM entity states](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

In your case, both entities are managed and therefore Hibernate ORM knows that it needs to apply the changes. `item3` is managed because it has been persisted, `order` is managed because it's the result of a `find`.

The javadoc for `session.save` starts with:

> Persist the given transient instance ...

None of the entities are transient in this case.

Note that you would be able to change the example, depending on how you map the association with different [cascade types](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade).

For example, if the association `items` is mapped using `CascadeType.PERSIST`, this would also work:

```
Order order = new Order();

Item item3 = new Item();
item3.setName("Third Item");

item3.setOrder(order);
order.getItems().add(item3);

// Both entities are transient in this case
em.persist(order);
```

Comment: Transient means that the object is not attached to the session. Updating an object doesn't make it transient. Check the article about the entity states I linked in the answer for more details.